# CFNetwork.framework deleted by mistake in xcode4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cfnetwork, ios-frameworks

I have included `CFNetwork.framework` in my app. And later when not required i just right click and deleted by mistake. Now my iPhone app is not getting built saying CFNetwork.h is missing.
In add libraries I searched but couldn't find the framework in the list.

(1) Is there any way to recover the deleted `CFNetwork.framework`.

(2) Is there any way to download this `framework` and add it to the `Xcode` or `SDK` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

1.Go to summary in xcode

2.Click the + button below linked binaries and frameworks

3.From there select your desired frame work and then click add

Now you have successfully added your framework to your project

Comment: I tried this and i am not finding CFNetwork.framework in that list. It seems it deleted the framework from SDK. :(

Comment: i just reinstalled Xcode.. i mean just double click worked. It replaced missing file.

Comment: -at- Melbourne
Once Any Framework/Library deleted from XCode it can not be found in Summary area of XCode.

@Sivannarayana
The Best Solution for it will be -> GoTo you "Trash" and check for deleted Framework, right click on it and press "Put Back" option.
Now re-open your XCode and check. Your framework will be re-stored. :)